# how to implement backward compatible (API 8 and higher) Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android

[This](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-43-and-updated-developer-tools.html) blog post says

> we've added an Action Bar API to let you build this essential Android
>   design pattern into your app with compatibility back to Android 2.1.

I used [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout) example to create a navigation drawer. But it's giving error on getActionBar when I run in it a 2.3.3 device.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity.getActionBar
```

How to fix this? A backward compatible navigation drawer is still not available to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`getSupportActionBar()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#getSupportActionBar%28%29) if you use the compatibility package.